# how to make first button not active when clicking second button

Tags: jquery

```
$("#editText,#edit-formula").click(function(){
      if($(this).hasClass("active")){ 
       $(this).siblings("button").removeClass("active");
    }
 });
```

Comment: Please add proper html. what does #editText,#edit-formula signify ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this :

```js
$("button.active").removeClass("active");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `addClass` and  `siblings` in single chaining method.

```js
$("#editText,#edit-formula").on("click", function() {
    $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass('active');
      
});
```

```css
.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='button' id='editText'>
<input type='button' id='edit-formula'>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just a example how it work**

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('button').click(function(){
            $(this).attr('disabled', true).siblings("button").attr('disabled', false);
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button">Hello</button>
    <button type="button">Bye</button>
```